# Highcharts remove renderer path

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Here is how it's added:

```
chart.renderer.path(['M', 1200, 10, 'V', 1500, 0])
            .attr({
                'stroke-width': 2,
                stroke: 'red'
            })
            .add();
```

But how to delete it?

```
var x = someValue;
chart.renderer.path(['M', x, 10, 'V', 1500, 0])
        .attr({
            'stroke-width': 2,
            stroke: 'red'
        })
        .add();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATED**

here is how you remove it [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/PEZjq/1/)

```
  function(chart) { // on complete

    chart.renderer.path(['M', 0, 0, 'L', 100, 100, 200, 50, 300, 100])
        .attr({
            'stroke-width': 2,
            stroke: 'red'
        })
        .add();
    $(":button").click(function(){
        $('path[d="M 0 0 L 100 100 200 50 300 100"]').remove() ;
         });
    });
```

*remove path by id*

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/PEZjq/2/)

```
    function(chart) { // on complete

    chart.renderer.path(['M', 0, 0, 'L', 100, 100, 200, 50, 300, 100])
        .attr({
            'stroke-width': 2,
            stroke: 'red' ,
            id :'myPath'
        })
        .add();
    $(":button").click(function(){
        $("#myPath").remove() ;
                                        });
     });
```

Comment: but I don't know the path values. I want all of them gone before I create new paths.

Comment: can you give us your full code or a jsFiddle , cause in your question you hard coded your path

Answer (score 15):

For future Googlers, this will work:

```js
var path = chart.renderer.path(['M', 1200, 10, 'V', 1500, 0])
.attr({
    'stroke-width': 2,
    stroke: 'red'
})
.add();

// remove the path
path.element.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that `element.remove()` works fine in Chrome, but not when running in a `WebView` on Android, for example, and may therefore not work in other browser environments.

Delving through the object's properties and methods, I found a `safeRemoveChild()` method, which seems to work even in a `WebView`.  So that's something along the lines of:

```
var path = chart.renderer.path(['M', 1200, 10, 'V', 1500, 0])
.attr({
    'stroke-width': 2,
    stroke: 'red'
})
.add();

// remove the path
path.safeRemoveChild(path.element);
```

Comment: thanks @drmrbrewer on IE11 `safeRemoveChild` did the trick, `element.remove()` is not recognized by IE

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using polymer or who just wants to do this using pure js, here's how to manage an object that will be created on load and then redrawn every time the chart updates:

http://jsfiddle.net/57xw879k/1/

The advantage of this is that it's added to the chart object, so you're not relying on the DOM or any particular method of accessing it.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events is also worth a read if you want to perform actions at different times.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>

<button id="remove">
  Remove label
</button>
<button id="add">
  Add label
</button>
```

JS:

```
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        handleLabel(this)
        var label = this.renderer.label('The chart was just redrawn', 100, 120)
        .attr({
          fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
          padding: 10,
          r: 5,
          zIndex: 8
        })
        .css({
          color: '#FFFFFF'
        })
        .add()
        setTimeout(function () {
          label.fadeOut()
        }, 1000)
      }
    }
  },
  title: {text: 'Highcharts label actions'},
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },    
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]    
})

function handleLabel(chart) {
    if (chart.myLabel) {
    chart.myLabel.destroy()
    addLabel(chart)
  } else {
    addLabel(chart)
  }
}

function addLabel(chart) {
  var point = chart.series[0].points[8];
  chart.myLabel = chart.renderer.label('Max observation', 270, 50, 'callout', point.plotX + chart.plotLeft, point.plotY + chart.plotTop)
    .css({
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    })
    .attr({
      fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
      padding: 8,
      r: 5,
      zIndex: 6
    })
    .add()
}

function removeLabel(chart) {
  !objectIsEmpty(chart.myLabel) && chart.myLabel && chart.myLabel.destroy()
}

function objectIsEmpty(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object
}

document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click', () => removeLabel(chart))
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', () => addLabel(chart))
```